# Числовой ключ объекта JS

Tags: javascript

```
var titleForm = {
    "3": "1a",
    "4": "1b", 
    "5": "1c"
}

var i = 0;
alert(titleForm.i); // Не работает
```

Как должно быть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пишите `alert(titleForm[i])` Дело в том, что когда вы пишите `alert(titleForm.i) javascript` ищет свойство объекта с именем i, а когда вы пишите `alert(titleForm[i]) javascript` ищет свойство объекта с именем значение переменной i.